Magnetic pendulum with magnetic bob
I've been reading about the common magnetic pendulum experiment in which a metal ball is swinging above more than 1 identical attracting neodymium magnets. magnetic pendulum experiment, is a demonstration of the experiment. Its acceleration is said to be governed using the equation below, but I am now wondering what would be the effect on the acceleration if the bob itself was a magnet, attracted those below and identical to them.
equation origin (Magnetic Pendulum).
image source The magnetic pendulum model
If anyone has an answer that would be greatly appreciated.
